# Remove a node from a network without affecting the interaction of others nodes

Tags: r, networkx, gephi, pgrouting

This is a sample of my big graph:

[image]

And i want to remove the node "B" without affecting the interaction of other nodes:

[image]

I worked it with "R", "PgRouting","gephi" and "networkx". And I dont found an efficient way to do it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using R and the `igraph` package:

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_graph(~ B -- A:C:D, A-E, C-F, D-G)
plot(g)
```

[image]

```
node <- "B"
g_2 <- 
  g %>% 
  union(connect(make_ego_graph(g, 1, node)[[1]], 2)) %>% 
  delete_vertices(node)
plot(g_2)
```

[image]